# Save changes before renaming

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

How can I add my own implementation to Rename context menu of eclipse explorer view. When I click on Rename I want to do some verification before I rename the project

```
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants">
  <renameParticipant
        class="core.ui.project.RenameProject"
        id="core.ui.renameParticipant"
        name="Rename">
  </renameParticipant>
```

```
public class RenameProject extends RenameParticipant {

@Override
protected boolean initialize(Object element) {
    System.out.println("HERE");
    return false;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    System.out.println("HERE");
    return null;
}

@Override
public RefactoringStatus checkConditions(IProgressMonitor pm, CheckConditionsContext context)
        throws OperationCanceledException {
    System.out.println("HERE");
    return null;
}

@Override
public Change createChange(IProgressMonitor pm) throws CoreException, OperationCanceledException {
    System.out.println("HERE");
    return null;
}

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the implementation of the menu in order to verify something during a rename.

Instead use the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants` extension point to define a 'rename participant' which will be called during rename operations. The participant can check that the rename is valid and add additional work to be done during the rename.

The participant code extends the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.RenameParticipant` class which is in the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring` plug-in.

There are also participants for create, copy, move and delete.

An example participant for file renames from the Ant plugin:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants">
  <renameParticipant
         class="org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.refactoring.LaunchConfigurationBuildfileRenameParticipant"
         name="%AntRenameParticipant.name"
         id="org.eclipse.ant.ui.refactoring.launchConfiguration.buildfileRename"> 
      <enablement>
        <with variable="element">
          <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
        </with>
      </enablement>
   </renameParticipant>
```

Comment: When I try to rename the project I get an error of resource out of sync, how can I make sure that its in sync before renaming the project

Comment: Can you provide some code to have an idea how can I use renameParticipants

Comment: There is lots of information on participants in the Eclipse help. I don't have any examples. Resource out of sync is a separate question.

Comment: Dont I have to implement IResourceChangeListener ?

Comment: Doing a rename from the menus will call the rename participants directly, it doesn't need any listeners

Comment: I mean calling rename when I right click on a project inside project explorer not from the menu

Comment: It makes no difference, any UI operation that does rename calls the rename participants.

Comment: I created a rename extension point and a class "RenameProject", does this class needs to implement a specific interface or extends a class? What should be core methods in this class that are called when renaming project in project exlporer

Comment: From the documentation: 'API Information: The contributed class must extend org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.RenameParticipant'

Comment: RenameParticipant class cannot be resolved into a type, I am using java 11

Comment: Add `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring` to the plug-in dependencies.

Comment: I extend my class from RenameParticipant and added breakpoints in all the methods when I right click on a project in project explorer and rename it none of the methods are called, I added my code above

Comment: You have to use the `<enablement>` element to say what sort of object the participant applies to